# Do you need to use getters when overriding toString? [Java]

Tags: java, class

From my understanding, since toString is converting the instance variable into a String anyway, there shouldn't be any privacy/security leaks issue from this right?

e.g.:

```
    //overriding toString method
    public String toString() {
        return ("Ticket Price: " + getTicketPrice() + "$ | Number of Stops: " + getNbStops() 
                + " | City Name: " + cityName);
```

Here, getTicketPrice() and getNbStops() are methods to get the values from a superclass. And "cityName" is an instance variable in the current class, so I'm calling it directly instead of using getCityName().

Is this safe practice?

Thanks.

Comment: *any privacy/security leaks issue* - what do you mean?

Comment: The advantage of using method calls in the toString method is that if you modify a get method, the modification is automatically made in the toString method.  Otherwise, using the instance variable is safe.

Comment: If the getters and their respective instance variables are defined in the superclass, then yes. The best practice here would be to use the getters. @Gilbert Le Blanc's point about `toString`'s output being modified when you modify the getters is also a plus.